# e.preventDefault prevents succeeding submit events

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an event listener for a form. If a validation fails, I call `e.preventDefault()`. A message is displayed to the user, they fix the error, and then attempt to submit the form again. The problem I am having is that the `e.preventDefault()` function is preventing the form from submitting again after the validation has failed. I get the idea that the event would need to be bound to the form element again but I am not sure the best method for fixing this issue. Here is my code:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
   let submitBtn = document.getElementById("cr-submit");
   submitBtn.disabled = true;
   if(validateForm() === false){
     submitBtn.disabled = false;
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}, false);
```

Comment: In order to help, please show the code of `validateForm()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my issue ended up being completely unrelated to `e.preventDefault()` and was actually caused by the framework I am using, Ruby on Rails. `RailsUJS` automatically disables the form submit button on submit. `jQuery`, which I was using previously worked fine with this implementation. However, when I converted the jQuery to plain `JS`, my code that enabled the field did not actually enable the field. It appears that `RailsUJS` was actually disabling the field after my listener had fired. So, I had to remove the auto-disable feature from my submit button and now I let my `JS` handle disabling that button.

```
<%= i.submit("Submit", data: { disable_with: false }) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the event object is new each time, so you don't have to "unprevent" the default behavior. It's more likely that the validateForm() function is returning false when you don't expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your `validateForm()` is not working as you intended because your code should submit when validateForm() !== false.  Maybe `validateForm()` is always returning false?